# Mismatched MySQL dates evaluate to equal

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select w.EventName, w.EventLocation, CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', w.RecurringEventTime) AS RecurringEventTime, w.OneTimeDateTime
from EventClickIns eci
join WebEvents w
on eci.WebEventID = w.ID
where eci.UserID = 493
and eci.WebEventID <> 10
and eci.InvitationID <> 175
and date(eci.ClickInDate) = date(now())
and (RecurringEventTime = '2018-03-19 12:00:00' OR w.OneTimeDateTime = '2018-03-19 12:00:00')
limit 1
```

And I get this record as the result:

```
EventName      EventLocation      RecurringEventTime     OneTimeDateTime
========================================================================
Evt ABC        123 Anystreet      2018-03-20 12:00:00    NULL
```

It's baffling why I am getting a matching record when the *RecurringEventTime* in my `where clause` is different from the *RecurringEventTime* in the matching record. *OneTimeDateTime* is *null*, so that cannot be matching.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the type of the field `RecurringEventTime` ?

Comment: You are tricking yourself. The value you are comparing in the `where` clause is the actual column value (the comparison is probably involving autocasting to a time?), the value you are displaying is `CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', w.RecurringEventTime)`, which you gave the alias `AS RecurringEventTime`, so it looks like the original column value (which it isn't anymore). You cannot use the alias in `where` (I assume this is what you are trying to do, try to rename it to get an error), but you can/have to e.g. repeat the `concat`-formula (or e.g. `addtime()`) there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hints from Sam and Solarflare, I got it figured out:

```
select w.EventName, w.EventLocation, CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', w.RecurringEventTime) AS RecurringEventTime, w.OneTimeDateTime
from EventClickIns eci
join WebEvents w
on eci.WebEventID = w.ID
where eci.UserID = 493
and eci.WebEventID <> 10
and eci.InvitationID <> 175
and date(eci.ClickInDate) = date(now())
and (CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', w.RecurringEventTime) = '2018-03-19 12:00:00' OR w.OneTimeDateTime = '2018-03-19 12:00:00')
limit 1
```